# How to save a hex file into Arduino Flash to send it via Serial?

Tags: serial, arduino-due, uart, flash

I have a text file with hex values formatted in the following style:

```
A0 3F 55 01 00 C7 55 01 00 C7 AA 29 71 11 00 0B
00 C7 AA 29 71 1F AA 29 71 11 55 01 A0 3F 55 DC
...
```

How can I save this data into my Arduino's Flash (to save RAM)? What libraries are needed? Is there any tool that can automatically create code for this purpose?

After I save this data into the Arduino's Flash, I want to send the data via Serial. I have to send it as binary.

A solution without saving it into the Flash would be also OK.

I am using an Arduino Due.

Comment: Flash program memory or flash EEPROM?

Comment: Flash program memory.

Comment: Use `objcopy` to turn it into a `.o` file, fabricate an appropriate `.h` file containing the symbols in the `.o` file, and then compile against the `.h` and link against the `.o`.

Comment: Replace the spaces with `,`, prepend `0x` to the start of each pair, so you get `0xA0, 0x3F, 0x55, ...`, then wrap it in `const byte myData[] PROGMEM = { ... your data ... };` - Personally I would write a small script to do it in Perl or PHP (I loathe Python with a passion).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to integrate this data into a `.ino` script.  Probably as a byte array. Then the script can read the array and `Serial.write` its content.

You could write a small tool in Python or else on your computer, that takes the text file and converts it into a `.h` header. Include that into your `.ino` script. Or use your favorite text editor to format the data into C++ code, and copy/paste that into your script.